# Unable to associate Array of Object value with another nested array of object property

Tags: google-apps-script

**Problem Statement**

I want to associate `_id` with the `entriesCount` count. I have successfully retrieved the following values mentioned below. **However, I am unable to associate ID with the corresponding entry count.**

**Values retrieved**

```
  data.totals.forEach(entry => console.log(entry.entriesCount)); // 2
  data.groupOne.forEach(entry => console.log(entry._id)); // XXXX
```

The final result will look like this:

[image]

**Consideration:**
Currently, in the API output below, there is only ONE user. I want the script to account for multiple users.

**Data Output for One User only**

```
{
   "groupOne":[
      {
         "children":[
            {
               "amounts":[
                  {
                     "type":"EARNED",
                     "value":0.0
                  }
               ],
               "_id":"651fa3da3ec2cb252c3b5ccb",
               "amount":0.0,
               "name":"API Testing",
               "duration":3600.0
            },
            {
               "amounts":[
                  {
                     "value":0.0,
                     "type":"EARNED"
                  }
               ],
               "duration":3600.0,
               "amount":0.0,
               "name":"Google App Script",
               "_id":"651fa3c5894cd94491aeb088"
            }
         ],
         "amounts":[
            {
               "value":0.0,
               "type":"EARNED"
            }
         ],
         "amount":0.0,
         "duration":7200.0,
         "nameLowerCase":"team",
         "name":"Team",
         "hasMembership":true,
         "_id":"651e64b63ec2cb252c188a16"
      }
   ],
   "totals":[
      {
         "entriesCount":2.0,
         "totalTime":7200.0,
         "totalBillableTime":7200.0,
         "_id":"",
         "amounts":[
            {
               "value":0.0,
               "type":"EARNED"
            }
         ],
         "totalAmount":0.0
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: [Edit] to provide correct js object. `=` is not a valid key-value separator in js. Use `console.log` instead of `Logger.log`

Comment: Also provide data for at least two users.

Comment: Data shown is not valid JSON.  Nor is is valid Object Notation

Comment: @Cooper I have updated the API response data output.

Comment: It's still not valid JavaScript Object Notation.  Try an online validator.

Comment: @Cooper I copied the API response above from the execution log in App Script

Comment: I don't care where you obtained it.  It's not in a form that's easy for us to use and I don't wish to have to go through it and edit it by hand.

Comment: @Cooper Apologies for earlier. I have updated the Javascript Object Notation. I used https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# to validate the format. It has given me green signal

Comment: It would make more sense to me if the values in you data agreed with the values in your table.  Otherwise I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual value from your API. But, from your showing sample value of `Currently, in the API output below, there is only ONE user.`, about `I want the script to account for multiple users.`, I guessed that the value might be as follows.

```json
{
  "groupOne": [
    {,,,},
    {,,,},
    {,,,},
  ],
  "totals": [
    {,,,},
    {,,,},
    {,,,},
  ]
}
```

If my understanding is correct, in order to retrieve your expected value, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const obj = {
  "groupOne": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "amounts": [
            {
              "type": "EARNED",
              "value": 0.0
            }
          ],
          "_id": "651fa3da3ec2cb252c3b5ccb",
          "amount": 0.0,
          "name": "API Testing",
          "duration": 3600.0
        },
        {
          "amounts": [
            {
              "value": 0.0,
              "type": "EARNED"
            }
          ],
          "duration": 3600.0,
          "amount": 0.0,
          "name": "Google App Script",
          "_id": "651fa3c5894cd94491aeb088"
        }
      ],
      "amounts": [
        {
          "value": 0.0,
          "type": "EARNED"
        }
      ],
      "amount": 0.0,
      "duration": 7200.0,
      "nameLowerCase": "team",
      "name": "Team",
      "hasMembership": true,
      "_id": "651e64b63ec2cb252c188a16"
    }
  ],
  "totals": [
    {
      "entriesCount": 2.0,
      "totalTime": 7200.0,
      "totalBillableTime": 7200.0,
      "_id": "",
      "amounts": [
        {
          "value": 0.0,
          "type": "EARNED"
        }
      ],
      "totalAmount": 0.0
    }
  ]
};

const values = obj.groupOne.map(({ _id }, i) => [_id || "", obj.totals[i].entriesCount || ""]);
console.log(values);
```

- If you want to put the values to the active sheet, as a simple script, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`.

#### Note:

- If my guess was not correct, can you provide the sample value including multiple users? By this, I would like to modify it.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Your guess was correct. I also tested out multiple users' API output but the entry counts were not broken down user-wise, so I will need to figure out which API endpoint does that. For now, I will work with your solution to send out emails to individual users. Thanks for your help.